# How can you find the Absorption of a specific compound in a solution with 2 other compounds using Uv spectrophotometer

Tags: organic-chemistry, uv-vis-spectroscopy

I was wondering if there was a way to get the absorption of ascorbic acid in a solution with citric acid and disodium hydrogen phosphate?

I’m thinking of measuring the absorption of disodium hydrogen phosphate and citric acid solution and then subtracting the solution with the all three molecules to get the absorption of ascorbic acid by itself. Would this be fine? If not what can I do?